# What kind of LTL formula can be represented by DBAs

Tags: automata, logic, linear-temporal-logic, buchi-automata

I am looking for the portion of LTL formula that can be expressed by deterministic buchi automata. Is there any classification of this such?

Comment: Yes; there are some canonical theorems. Where have you looked?

Comment: Could you please give me some references on those theorems?

Comment: Not at the moment, sorry. Since I learned about them in a course, I'd assume any book on either topic would include them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define syntactic fragments of LTL that ensure that all properties expressible in these fragments are representable as DBAs. An example is given in the paper "[A LTL Fragment for GR(1)-Synthesis](http://es.cs.uni-kl.de/publications/datarsg/MoSc11a.pdf)". Also, the [common fragment of ACTL and LTL](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.2000.892332) only contains properties that are representable as DBAs.

But note that such a fragment will never be complete in the "if a formula is not in the fragment, then it is not representable as a DBA" sense. The reason is that if we have LTL formulas that are not representable as DBAs, then we may be able to combine them to a formula that *is* representable as DBA. For example, the properties "FG p | GF q" and "FG q | GF p" are both not expressible by DBA, but both their conjunction and their disjunction are.

Note that there are also DBAs that are not representable in LTL. So a fragment of LTL cannot be equiexpressive to DBAs.